# How would i make a cat script that sanitises it's input?

Tags: haproxy, cat, lets-encrypt

I am experimenting with load balancers on my infrastructure which is protected by letsencrypt.

I followed a blog article https://blog.bigdinosaur.org/finally-moving-to-letsencrypt-with-haproxy-varnish-and-nginx/

which has worked very well the problem I am having is letsencrypt support SAN (Subject Access Names) the script generates the certificates properly but the cat command it uses to automate combining the certificate and the private key does not support having commas in it.

for example the script to run would be le-renew.sh domain.tld,www.domain.tld

This issues the certificate using the normal certbot procedure.

it then attempts to run cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld,www.domain.tld/fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld,www.domain.tld/privkey.pem

This is where it fails with the error of No Such File or directory which is understandable seen as certbot creates the file /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem

Is there a way to make the cat script ignore whats between the comma and the slash so it matches certbot's way of doing things?

Sorry if that was a bit of a ramble.